# How to insert color code for two geom_step functions in the same grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently working in a comparison between two inventory levels and I want to plot two step graphs in the same grid with a color code. This is my code.

```
Intento1<-data.frame(Fecha, NivelI)
Intento2<-data.frame(Fecha, Nivel2)
#Printing the step graphs in one grid
ggplot()+geom_step(Intento1, mapping=aes(x=Fecha, y=NivelI))+geom_step(Intento2, mapping=aes(x=Fecha, y=Nivel2))
```

And it works fine plotting both graphs in the same grid, I could also add a different color to each graph but I couldn´t add the little colored labels that appear normally at the right. All support is appreciated. [image: What I get using my code]

Answer (score 0):

For example data `dummy`,

```
dummy <- data.table(
  Fecha = seq(as.Date("2020/1/1"), as.Date("2020/1/31"), "day")
)

dummy$NivelI = runif(31, 0, 10)
dummy$Nivel2 = runif(31, 0, 10)
```

plot using `reshape2::melt` like below will work.

```
dummy %>%
  melt(id.vars = "Fecha") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Fecha, value, group = variable, color = variable)) +
  geom_step() + guides(color = guide_legend(title = "aaa"))
```

[image]

In your case, to make `dummy` formed data, if `Fecha`, `NivelI` and `Nivel2` are vectors, just try

```
df <- data.frame(
 Fecha,
 NivelI,
 Nivel2
)
```

then

```
df %>%
      melt(id.vars = "Fecha") %>%
      ggplot(aes(Fecha, value, group = variable, color = variable)) +
      geom_step() + guides(color = guide_legend(title = "aaa"))
```

where `"aaa"` will be your legend name.

Comment: I owe you my life, it worked fine and you saved my final project. Thank you so much.